# Reviews: should I click No Action Needed, or Skip, when I can't edit?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing posts on a site I don't yet have edit privileges on, occasionally I'll come across a post that needs editing, but the 'edit' option is greyed out. My understanding is that this is due to an already pending suggested edit.

In these cases - assuming no other action is required - should I click 'No Action Needed', or 'Skip'?

Comment: You should click 'skip'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two main reasons why you should click Skip, and not No Action Needed:

1. Action is needed (an edit must be approved); you simply can't carry out the action.
2. If you click No Action Needed, it will remove the item from the queue, making it a bit harder for other reviewers who *can* approve the edit to see it - although the edit should still be in the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: Thanks @HDE. I guess I was thinking - action is needed, but it has already been taken (an edit). The action that is still needed is approving the edit, but that's for a different queue, and (as far as I know), the edit can only be approved in the Suggested Edits queue (although it could just be overriden in another queue by a 2k+ rep user if they edit it directly).

Comment: NAN does in fact remove the item from the queue immediately. And sometimes the edit suggestion is far from complete, addressing only one or two bits of a post that needs either a more comprehensive overhaul or condemnation.

Comment: I've accepted this answer primarily because of the point @NathanO'TᴇstingTuggy makes :)